# Prevent default on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Drop Down Called Network. For a Particular network we can enter number of contracts. Lets say We enter 3 Contract for a network. And if a user mistakenly changes the drop down then all the 3 contracts will be wiped out.

So what I am trying to do is give a warning dialog with OK or Cancel. If they click OK then the new Network from the Drop Downlist is selected and all the contracts are wiped out, if they click Cancel then there wont be any change.

I am trying to use e.PreventDefault() and placing that before the warning dialog. But the Drop Down Item is changed even before the warning dialog is popped out. And since it is drop down change event, e.PreventDefault is not working.

Can anyone please help me.

```
 function networkIdChangeEvent(event) {
   if (atLeastOneContract()) {
     event.preventDefault();
     showWarningDialog(closeDialogMsg, okFunction, cancelFunction)
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: can you show the actual event handler? this just appears to be the function that it calls, how are you calling this?

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to instead

> return false

that should work on an eventListener if jQuery event handler. If non-Jquery event then Note: The preventDefault() method does not prevent further propagation of an event through the DOM. Use the stopPropagation() method to handle this.

Comment: onchange is non-cancelable event so return false, stopPropagation(), and preventDefault() will not help. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        (function () {
            for (var i = 0, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
                var elem = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
                elem.prevValue = elem.value;
                elem.onchange = function (e) {
                    console.log('prev ' + this.id + '; ' + this.prevValue);
                    var ok = confirm('Are you sure?');
                    if (ok)
                        this.prevValue = this.value;
                    else
                        this.value = this.prevValue;
                    console.log('new ' + this.id + '; ' + this.prevValue);
                }
            }
        })('sel', 'sel1');
    }
</script>
```

Your dropdowns:

```
    <select id="sel">
        <option value="-1">select</option>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
    </select>
    <select id="sel1">
        <option value="-1">select</option>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
    </select>
```

I hope this idea will be useful.